# android negative top margin not working

Tags: android, css, android-relativelayout, margin

I have encountered a problem where i try to give an ImageView a negative top margin. When i do this, the ImageView isn't showed anymore, although if i use a negative left margin and a positive top margin everything works fine. Anyone can help me out? I add my ImageView in a relative layout
my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/file_detail_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How i add the Imageviews

```
RelativeLayout l = ((RelativeLayout)(rootView.findViewById(R.id.file_detail_layout)));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(preview.getWidth(), preview.getHeight());
        params.leftMargin = 50;
        params.topMargin = 60;
        l.addView(imgView, params);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(preview.getWidth(), preview.getHeight());
        params.leftMargin = -10;
        params.topMargin = -10;
        l.addView(imgView2, params);
```

ps: I do see imgView, but imgView2 doesn't show up.

Comment: What's the height of the `imgView2` ? If it's below 10 units, then that's why it doesn't show-up. And does it appear when you scroll-up?

Comment: No it doesn't show up, and imgView2 both height and width are 256 pixels.

Comment: What's the minSDK in the ManifesT?